# is it possible snprintf return char array beginning with '\0'?

Tags: c++, linux

I have the following code :

```
string getid()
{   
    pthread_t tid = pthread_self();
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    uint64_t t = static_cast<uint64_t>(tv.tv_sec);
    char buf[64];
    snprintf(buf, 64, "%ld-%ld", static_cast<uint64_t>(tid), static_cast<uint64_t>(t));

    return buf;
}
```

sometimes, the returned string has 0 size(), I think one possible reason is buf[0] is '\0', that means pthread_self return '\0' beginning char array?

Comment: Just a nitpick, for unsigned integers you should say `%u`, but for fixed-width integers you should be using the macros from `inttypes.h` anyway.

Comment: the above code should not produce an empty string (i.e. `buf[0] = '\0'` you could e.g. put an `assert(buf[0] != '\0')` after the `snprintf` statement. Or put an `if` statement printing a warning (and then set a breakpoint in the debugger on the line where the warning is printed etc.)

Comment: @Andre Holzner : it could produce an empty string, if the `snprintf` call failed to write the first value into the buffer eg. (and the first byte in `buf` happened to be a `'\0'`).

Comment: I just make a experiment: create 100 threads each of which execute the above getid() 10000 times, bug[0] never be '\0'. I am so confused.

Comment: @Raymond : In which case does it give you an empty string ? What's special about that case ? How does it differ from your experimental setup ? What does `snprintf` return in that case ?

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_self` returns a `pthread_t`, which is not necessarily an integer type. So your cast might not even make sense.

Next, `%ld` refers to a `long int`, but you're passing `uint64_t` values. Depending on the size of a `long int` on your system, that might again not make much sense.

But, to get to your question : check the return value of the `snprintf` call : it returns the number of characters that have been successfully written. If it's not at least 3, then something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

to printf a 64bit number, it is not `%ld`. The most portable is using the very ugly `PRIu64` like:

```
printf("%"PRIu64"\n", u64);
```

But I think `%llu` might also work on your platform.

As other have pointed out, you are returning a pointer to an auto array, meaning it will reside in temporary storage (can in some cases not be the stack). Either return the pointer to an array allocated by `new` or if you do not need to be reentrant, declare the buffer `static`, but this is not a very good solution, allocating it on the heap with `new` would be preferred.

Comment: there is no pointer being returned - just a `string` (presumably `std::string`) object constructed from the contents of `buf`. So, that part is not a problem. The inconsistent usage of types though, is.

Comment: Yes, the type is used inconsistently, thank you. But I still don't know why the returned string has size 0 sometimes in online scenario.